# Can't stash changes with Git

Tags: git, webstorm

I have changed some files and I want to stash these changes but when I run;

```
git stash save "teststash"
```

from command line, It gives error;

```
Cannot save the current index state
```

I am using Webstorm and also I cannot stash any changes with it also. WebStorm gives same error;

```
tried to save uncommitted changes in stash before merge, but failed with an error. 
Couldn't stash file://C:/Projects/myproject: Cannot save the current index state
```

**EDIT:**

```
git -status
```

Here is the output of status command;

```
On branch branch111
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/branch666'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   package-lock.json

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    sh.exe.stackdump

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I added output of git status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git stash save` is deprecated as of 2.15.x/2.16.

You may use `git stash push -m "message"` where "message" is your note for that stash.

If you wish to retrieve the stash, first list all the the stashed items and choose the suitable one.

use `git stash list` to list out all the stashed items. And to apply any stashed item `git stash apply stash@{<stash_id>}`

Git Stash Document: [Git Stash Man Page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--ltpathspecgt82308203)

Comment: That *shouldn't* make any difference here because `git stash save` still invokes the saving code, just like `git stash push`: it just doesn't give you the ability to use some of the new flags and other arguments. The failure message shown in the question suggests some sort of temporary permissions issue was going on. Still, `git stash push` is the modern command, and people should switch to it.